# Extending permissions in Drupal

Tags: drupal, permissions, view

suppose i have a drupal module called question/answer that is a user post(question) that is later modified by a moderator(answer). i also have several categories under which questions are created. now a moderator can edit ANY question but i want to assign a separate moderator for each category so that he can't edit the questions of other categories.

is it possible to do?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to approach this.

**Using [Taxonomy Access](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access) or the [TAC Lite](http://drupal.org/project/tac_lite) module**

Where each category is it's own taxonomy term and separations are created by those vocabularies

**Using [Organic Groups](http://drupal.org/project/og)**

You can have a group for each category.  Then you can use [og_user_roles](http://drupal.org/project/og_user_roles) to create group roles within that group.  Each group role can have specific abilities.

**Custom module**

If you are using Drupal 6, you can use [hook_access](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--node.php/function/hook_access/6) to create those delineations.  I would use taxonomy to create the categories.  You will need to create an interface to assign roles to different taxonomies - basically what TAC Lite does.

Comment: Hook access only works for the module that owns the node type, in this case the forum module. So this wouldn't work without hacking that module.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Taxonomy access control](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access) to handle the permissions, by using taxonomy to determine the catagory.